# web based open source FTP

Tags: php, ftp

I need help on looking for a best solution of a web based open source FTP client that has a progress bar, e-mail notifications and easy file sharing with others.

I am looking to set up one for our print department, and you send it is really getting expensive.

I've look into net2ftp.com but styling it, is a bit pain in the bumbum....Also, Uploadify is also an option but with my lack of PHP knowledge I can't make it to actually do what I want it to do.

Let me know if you have buymp into and interesting tool like it.

Comment: So you don't actually need `FTP` access, but want a shared / controlled web-based file sharing solution, correct?

Comment: I don't know if https://DropBox.com/ does what you want.

Comment: yeah, your question used to say you wanted a web-based solution.  you edited the question?

Comment: no i didn't edit the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use [drop.io](http://drop.io)?  It's free up to 100MB, pretty inexpensive after that.  Just like YouSendIt, but they also have some "collaborative" features that allow you to share documents online with your group.

Answer (score 0):

I've used ES File Uploader by EnergyScripts:
http://www.energyscripts.com/Products/product2.html
Works great, allows non-technical users upload files to designated directories. I have it set up on our cub scout site so that the den leaders can upload PDFs for permission forms, etc.. 
Not open-source, but there's a lite/free version.

Comment: Hmm. Not so relevant now that the question has been re-worded..

Answer (score 0):

Since a "web based FTP server" doesn't really exist, [HFS File Server](http://www.rejetto.com/hfs/) (beta version needed for user auth) would work great, especially when combined with (the unmanaged version!!) of Hamachi for chat and SSL features.   You would get a HTTP web interface with download and upload capability, authentication as well as anonymous access controls, SSL Tunnel, and chat .  Everthing you need and very simple to setup and distribute.

Comment: I really don't like links directly to executable files.   Particularly when the domain name does not clearly suggest that it belongs to a single product.  It probably isn't the case here, but I do get worried that what you are linking to is malware.

Comment: I know you are worried but its ok. They are products that I have used for years and its totally safe. Do a google search if you want. I provided a link to the download because its otherwise hard to find the latest version of the download without having to snoop around. The link saves time for the guy who asked the question. Anyway, I fixed the link for you and so no worries.

Answer (score 0):

Standard FTP via the command line can display progress by turning on hashes.

You can write a shell script to monitor a directory and send emails upon changes.

FireFTP is a free add-on for firefox that provides an FTP client integrated with Firefox.